# C++ - Building Addition Tables

Tags: c++, loops

I am  having some troubles with this problem presented from my lab. My goal is to produce an addition table that looks something like this -

(From range(1-5)) :

```
+    1    2    3    4    5
1    2    3    4    5    6   
2    3    4    5    6    7
3    4    5    6    7    8
4    5    6    7    8    9
5    6    7    8    9    10
```

Mine is looking like this, however :

```
+    1    2    3    4    5
     2    3    4    5    6
     3    4    5    6    7
     4    5    6    7    8
     5    6    7    8    9
```

My code looks like this :

```
if (choice == ADD) {
    cout << "+";
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        cout << "\t";
        for (int j = min; j <= max; j++) {
            cout << i + j << "\t";
        }
    }
}
```

(For reference, int max = maximum number in range, int min = minimum number in range, and choice is the decision for user to do either an addition or multiplication table). How can I change my code to fit the proper format? I can't seem to figure it out. Any hints/help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Before the tab, just print out the value of `i`. Or alternatively start with `min = 0` and don't print out the initial tab. (Note: You can make your question clearer by showing the code that defines `min`, `max`, and `choice` rather than describing these in English.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int max = 5;
    int min = 1;

    if (true){
        cout << "+\t";//print out the initial +
        for(int i = min; i <= max; i++) cout << i << "\t";//print out the entire first row
        cout << "\n"; //start the next row

        //here is the main loop where you do most of the logic
        for(int i = min; i <= max; i++){
            cout << i << "\t"; //this prints out the first column of numbers
            for(int j = min; j <=max; j++){
                cout << j+i << "\t"; //this line fills in the body of your table
            }
            cout << "\n";//creates the space between each row
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Caleb. That clears up a lot of my confusion, and is a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

This code builds the table as explained:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
    if (i == 0)
        cout << '+';
    else
        cout << i;

    cout << '\t';
    for (int j = min; j <= max; j++) {
        cout << i + j << '\t';
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

**Tip**: when you want to print only a character, it is more efficient to use single quotes like `'+'` or `'\t'`. Double quotes are more expensive because they represent a `const char*`.

Comment: Good to know, Hugo. I really appreciate the tip. As you can surely tell, I am a beginner to C++, so knowing the most efficient way to go about things is great for me. Thanks again!